# json webmethod result incorrect format "error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI"

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am using Nicolas's Pivot control (nicolas.kruchten pivottable) and I'm trying to bind json result from a web method. I can accomplish this if I use a predefined class and return the list as that type, but my query to the database will not always be the same, the fields will differ from one instance to the other. 
I have used multiple methods to return the json (serializer list, json serialize dictionary, dataset AsEnumerable.ToList) and all of these methods returned results to the client side but the format is incorrect.

The format should be as in fig 1, the result that I get is in fig 2.
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/362Ia.png)
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML3R5.png)

Below is one of the tried methods, how can this be changed to return an array like result without having a pre-defined array object type?

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function DataTableToJSON()
    Dim strCN As String = "...
    ...

    da.Fill(ds)

    cmd = Nothing
    cn.Close()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim list = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()

        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

            For Each col As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
                dict(col.ColumnName) = row(col)
            Next
            list.Add(dict)
        Next
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Return serializer.Serialize(list)
    End If
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had to de-serialize the string with jQuery.parseJSON

```
$("#output").pivotUI(jQuery.parseJSON(mps.d));
```